# maven spring dependency version issue in two application

Tags: java, spring, maven, version

we have application A which is using spring 3.2 and application B which is using spring 4.2. App-A uses Jar of App-B (app-B.jar). when App-A calls one method of App-B this method return an object of spring 4.2 class and casting the same object into app-A into spring 3.2 reference. now in spring 3.2 methods are deprecated.

At run time i am getting unsupported operation as method is deprecated.

how to solve this situation without changing dependency version of each application ?

Comment: What you need to to is have a transformation jar which will handle the calls an respond with appropriate version response.

Comment: what is  transformation jar i am not aware about this can you elaborate a bit.

Answer (score 0):

How about you create your own version of this object? ApplicationB could then convert **Objectv4.2** to **CustomObject** and return this custom object instead.

Then ApplicationA could convert **CustomObject** into **Objectv3.2**.

I don't know the structure of your Object, but you could consider using a mapper framework (just to name a few):

- [Dozer](http://dozer.sourceforge.net)
- [Orika](http://orika-mapper.github.io)
- [ModelMapper](http://modelmapper.org)

All this assumes you are using this "Object" as a simple pojo, not actual spring bean bound to the spring lifecycle. Otherwise, a simple getter/setter conversion would not be sufficient.

I have no affiliation to any of these frameworks.

Answer (score 0):

Its a huge problem we faced in our project. We had to make sure all the dependent projects are spring upgraded before we upgrade the parent ones. Essentially you need to upgrade project A to 4.2 or above. Other wise you may end up in problems